# Accent error in PHP x MYSQL, using UTF8_encode() and UTF8_decode()?

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I am having problems with accentuation in a project that I am giving maintenance.

> > Table MYQL using utf8_unicode_ci

**String Error**

```
$text = 'SÃ£o Josï¿½'; #correct São José
echo utf8_decode($text); #print São Jos�
echo utf8_encode($text); #print SÃÂ£o JosÃ¯Â¿Â½
```

How to solve using php 5.6?

Comment: let me know the original string language.

Comment: is pt-BR (Brazilian)

Comment: Hex `EFBFBD` represents the "Replacement Character".  In certain situations, it shows as `ï¿½`.  So, I suspect you mangled the data in an attempt to fix it, and now there are _two_ errors to undo.  You will probably have to start over and establish the use of utf8 (or utf8mb4) and several points in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Before you fetch result from the database, fire below query,

```
SET NAMES UTF8;
```

This will set the character-set and the results returned will be proper.